# Angular component not identified

Tags: angular

I have the following structure of my application:

```
app
|-- author
|-- |-- posts
|-- |-- |-- posts.component.html
|-- |-- author.component.html
|-- 
|-- components
|-- |-- tag
|-- |-- |-- tag.component.ts

|-- home
|-- |-- home.component.html
|-- |-- ...
|-- ...
app.module.ts
graphql.module.ts
```

The problem is I can access my `components/tag` component in `home.component.html` but not able to access it in `author/posts/posts.component.html` & not even in `author/author.component.html`.

I have imported the `tag` component in my `app.module.ts` file & works fine for home. I am unable to detect the issue!

**Please help me in solving it**

**Edit:**
`app.module.ts`

```js
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";

//& Root
import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app-routing.module";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
//& Components
import { TagComponent } from "./components/tag/tag.component";
//& Routes
import { HomeComponent } from "./home/home.component";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    //& Routes
    HomeComponent,
    //& Components
    TagComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    //& Essential Modules
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    GraphQLModule,
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

`home.component.html`, `posts.component.html`

```html
<tag></tag>
```

Comment: Can you check, is your `tag.component` and `posts.component` resides in the same module `app.module` ?

Comment: Yes they both are declared in `app.module.ts` file

Comment: Can you tell me how you are trying to access it or you have accessed it from `home.component` ?

Comment: Can you add the modules?

Comment: do the files `tag.component.ts` and `posts.component.ts` exist (Note the `TS` ending for typescript and not html) and if they do, do they exist at the specified path in app.module.ts...

Comment: Yes they exist, but what do you mean by specific paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are declaring TagComponent in AppModule. That means that TagComponent is only visible to components declared in that module like HomeComponent. You have PostsComponent declared in other module (I'm guessing GraphQLModule) so it doesn't have acces to TagComponent.

You have several options:

- Declare PostComponent in AppModule
- Create a SharedModule which exports TagComponent an import it in the module that declares PostsComponent.
- Declare TagComponent in the module that declares PostComponent.

The main idea is that you need the components to see each other declared in the same module or imported by a module that exports them.